# PyCharm debugging - set next statement

Tags: debugging, pycharm

Does PyCharm have a "set next statement" capability while debugging, like Visual Studio with PTVS, Eclipse, and Wing IDE?

"set next statement" moves the execution point (forward or back), skipping intermediate statements, and is not the same as any of the run to cursor options.

[Visual Studio set next statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09yze4a9(v=vs.100).aspx)

UPDATE: Dec-1-2017  PyCharm 2017.3 Nov-29-2017 now includes this feature. It's described in What's New as "Set Next Statement". On the PyCharm menu, it's "Jump To Cursor". I tested this and it seems to work.

Comment: How do you mean?  One would set the next break point they want to hit in the same manner that they hit their first break point.

Comment: A breakpoint runs all the code between the two. OP wants to skip them, making the new point the next statement to be executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems Pydev's debugger has this feature (`Ctrl`+`f` on the [releases page](http://pydev.org/history_pydev.html) to find "set next statement", release 3.3.3).

Since Pycharm's debugger has been [merged with Pydev's](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/#Attach) (Pydev release 3.7.0), it should technically be available. Yet I couldn't find a single mention of that, neither in Pycharm's doc nor in its issue tracker.

I think it's not available quite yet.

Comment: There is a "run to cursor" option, but I think that's not what you want since it doesn't skip frames.

Comment: This may be the correct answer (and what I assumed to be true), even though disappointing. But maybe there is some way via the console if the capability is in the debugger.

Comment: 'run to cursor' is not what we want when it takes 57 seconds to run it from the start.  We need to be able to go back a few statements without rerunning everything.